# non-deterministic automaton and regular expression

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-expressions, finite-automata

I am a linguistics and I start to read some books about Nlp. I have to design a non-deterministic automaton and regular expression over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ that accept all and only those strings that contain exactly three a's, three b's, or three c's, not necessarily consecutively .for example;  strings l.ike $\{aaa, abaab, abbcccccccccccbaaa,cbccbbbbbbb,..\}$ is accepted.

Thanks all

Comment: How does $abaab$ is accepted? there only two $b$'s

Comment: It contains 3 a's.

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55510/755).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions it would be:

```
[bc]*a[bc]*a[bc]*a[bc]*
```

(logical or with its versions with b and c, left as exercise for the reader)

https://regex101.com/r/mI5dM4/1

(Only the 3 a version, and include \b for word boundary)

It matches any (possibly empty) sequence of non-'a' characters, exactly 3 times interrupted by an 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is that define NFA with states like $q_{ijk}$ where $i,j,k \in \{0,1,2,3,n \}$ that $i$ determine the number of $a$ and $j$ determine the number of $b$ and $k$ determine the number of $c$. when an index is $n$ means its greater than $3$. you can easly define function of NFA as when read $a$ just from $q_{ijk}$ goto $q_{i+1jk}$ and if $i=n$ stay at the state. start state is $q_{000}$ and all $q_{ijk}$ that at leas one of its index is 3 is the final state. its almost DFA so you can decrease the number of state if you want.

Comment: Karo, I need more explanation. I could speak Farsi too. Also, I have the picture of I automata how could I send it to you. I really need to answer these two questions as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I recomend you to download JFlap application. you can download it from internet. you can design NFA there and then convert it to an DFA and minimize the size of it. you can also run automata that you design on an input. @liza